# Using a dyn.com dynamic host name with an AirPort device

Tags: airport, dns, bonjour

I have an AirPort Extreme base station with firmware 7.6.1 and would like to access it remotely using a dynamic hostname registered with **dyn.com** (e.g. `example.dyndns.org`).

An [explanation](http://dyn.com/support/bonjour-and-dns-discovery/) is given by **dyn.com** on how to do this using zone updates and how to configure an AirPort device. But from reading the explanation I'm not sure whether this is only possible for domain names (like `example.com`) that use **dyn.com**'s name servers or also for dynamic hostnames.

Is it possible to use the AirPort device's DNS update capability to update a dynamic hostname registered with **dyn.com** and is it also possible to advertise service over Bonjour over this dynamic hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the page referenced in the question:

> Note on DynDNS Free and DynDNS Pro: We currently do not support Wide Area Bonjour on our DynDNS Free and Pro services. You must use Dyn Standard DNS **with your own domain name** for this to work properly.

So it won't work with dynamic `dns.com` addresses.

Comment: Does this also exclude updating the A record using RFC 2136 (which is what is used AFAIK) or just registering services?

Comment: I just found the same statement on [a page](http://dyn.com/support/airport-time-capsule-with-dynamic-dns/) talking specifically about just updating the IP Address on a DNS record from an AirPort device. Could you expand your answer to be more explicit on that?

Comment: Looks like they are experimenting with Bonjour for dynamic DNS as well. It's worth to give it a try.